# Design a neural network to predict array of numbers in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm new to machine learning and have little experience with ML libraries. I'm developing a neural network to predict array of numbers given an input array. So my input is like follows:

> Input to the neural network is a array of length 100.

And the output:

> Output of the model is array of length 60.

Here I post my code so far. It is currently not working. Can someone help me to do this in a correct way?

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(768, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(768, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(60, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
         loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
         metrices = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train_new, y_train_new, epochs = 20)
```

**Note:** `x_train_new` is a array of arrays of length 100 and `y_train_new` is a array of arrays of length 60.

When I run this and call `model.fit()` following error will be appeared.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-33e8f1dfe4c8> in <module>()
      5 # print(y_train_new.shape)
      6 
----> 7 model.fit(x_train_new, y_train_new, epochs = 20)

/home/vajira/tf_cpu_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1276         steps_name='steps_per_epoch',
   1277         steps=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1278         validation_split=validation_split)
   1279 
   1280     # Prepare validation data.

/home/vajira/tf_cpu_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split)
    915           feed_output_shapes,
    916           check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 917           exception_prefix='target')
    918 
    919       # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

/home/vajira/tf_cpu_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    189                 'Error when checking ' + exception_prefix + ': expected ' +
    190                 names[i] + ' to have shape ' + str(shape) +
--> 191                 ' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    192   return data
    193 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_14 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (60,)
```

Comment: could you tell us a bit more why it is not working? for example, the error it gives would be a good start...

Comment: @Alexis error is posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the input shape for the first layer:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(100,)))
```

However, if the input is a vector of length 100, then there is no need for a `Flatten` layer as it is already flattened. Instead, set the `input_shape` for the first `Dense` layer and remove the `Flatten` layer.

**Update:** Regarding the shape mismatch error, either use `categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function and pass one-hot encoded labels of size 60, or use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and pass integer labels (i.e. 0 or 1 or 2, etc.). Don't mix these two things: currently you are using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and pass one-hot encoded labels to `fit()` method. Therefore you get the shape mismatch error.

---

**Side note:** as @Alexis mentioned in the comments, please add the error you get (if applicable) when asking questions.